# What is missing from my log4j configuration that org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version requires?

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, log4j

I'm trying to figure out why our Hibernate code is not logging anything to log4j.  I put together a simple project that calls one Hibernate service method that logs a log4j message as the first line.

Both the project and the Hibernate service have the following log4j specific code:

```
private static Logger NTEVENT_LOG = Logger.getLogger("NTEVENT");
NTEVENT_LOG.debug("==== LOG4J logging");
```

When I run the project (Eclipse->run) I get the following messages in red:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

But immediately after I see the logging from the application itself so some part of log4j did get correctly initialized.  However, nothing is being logged by the Hibernate service.

```
[main] DEBUG NTEVENT  - ==== LOG4J logging
```

This is my log4j.xml

```
<appender name="NTEVENT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
</appender> 

<root> 
    <priority value ="debug" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="NTEVENT" /> 
</root>
```

I must be missing something that Hibernate is expecting but I have no idea what.

Comment: Try to put something like "log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG" (sorry, this is for plain config file, not xml)

Answer (score 0):

To configure log4j using xml file you need to use DOMConfigurator.configure() method in your main.

Also for this method you need to import **org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator** package.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");

..//your code
..
}
```

Hope this helps..!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was as ThrashBean implied, logging for org.hibernate was not enabled.  If you  want to see Hibernate debugging output, queries for instance, you need:

Comment: For some reason the  code did not survive that last comment. Here it is: <logger name="org.hibernate">
     <level value="... any log4j level ..." />
     <appender-ref ref="... an appender ..."/>
 </logger>

Answer (score 0):

I finally got what was happening in my case. It might also help those in Netbeans users facing the same problem coz i have lost a lot of hair for quite some months now. My application had just stopped logging to console so i couldnt debug since the errors were not being displayed.

The answer "There are two log4j jar files in you libraries at different location." was true. Initially i had expected to find 2 files with the name log4xxx.jar of course with different version numbers but no file like that at all was there. You see Netbeans comes prepackaged with Hibernate libraries and many other libraries of course. So when developing in hibernate applications in Netbeans you DON'T need to manually add your own Hibernate Jars unless of course you need a specific version etc, you can just add the Hibernate library to your application via that right click project - Properties - Libraries - Add Library button . This will add many hibernate Jars in the background/classpath when running and also on Compiling in the dist/lib folder BUT NOT in the lib of the application. In my case i had added both the Hibernate Library AND also copied the generated hibernate jars from dist/lib to lib. This had happened by mistake as i copied libraries from previous application to include in my new application for use there.

So take home point, if in Netbeans, go to your lib folder, if you see jars like 
hibernate-commons-annotations-x.x.x.Final.jar, hibernate-core-x.x.x.Final.jar,hibernate-entitymanager-x.x.x.Final.jar,  hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-x.x.x.Final.jar, hibernate-tools-x.x.x.CR1.jar
Remove them and check if error resolves.